# How to interpret Seaborn's regplot() when using x_bins?

Tags: seaborn

I'm walking through a course on Seaborn and I'm having trouble understanding how exactly the `x_bins` parameter in Seaborn's `seaborn.regplot()` function works.

The documentation has the below:

> Bin the x variable into discrete bins and then estimate the central tendency and a confidence interval. This binning only influences how the scatterplot is drawn; the regression is still fit to the original data. This parameter is interpreted either as the number of evenly-sized (not necessary spaced) bins or the positions of the bin centers.

So I understand that when I mention, say, `x_bins = 5`, seaborn will bin the X-axis such that there is an equal (as much as possible) number of observations in each bin. And if I mention something like `sns.regplot(data=mpg, x="weight", y="mpg", x_bins=np.arange(2000, 5500, 250), order=2)` (as given in the docs), the numbers are taken to be the bin centres.

My question: what exactly are the bin edges then? For example:

1. [In this figure from the docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Ky8.png), what are the first and second bins? Is it 1500 to some number between 1500 to 2,250?
2. In [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2VOR.png) (from a DataCamp course), produced through the code below (by specifying the number of bins), is the first bin 0.0 to ~0.25, and the second bin ~0.25 to somewhere under ~0.4?

I'm having trouble understanding the creation of bins and where exactly the point representing the mean is made.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for calculating the bins can be found in the [`bin_predictor` method of the `_RegressionPlotter` class](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/a3cb0f1b33551eb25fed1907d0abdd0237fac215/seaborn/regression.py#L333):

```py
def bin_predictor(self, bins):
    """Discretize a predictor by assigning value to closest bin."""
    x = np.asarray(self.x)
    if np.isscalar(bins):
        percentiles = np.linspace(0, 100, bins + 2)[1:-1]
        bins = np.percentile(x, percentiles)
    else:
        bins = np.ravel(bins)

    dist = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(x, bins))
    x_binned = bins[np.argmin(dist, axis=1)].ravel()

    return x_binned, bins
```

It determines the center of the bins using `np.linspace` and `np.percentile`, after which the distance for each point to the bin centers are calculated. The points are then assigned to the bins with the closest distance.